# Why does bagging increase bias?

Tags: machine-learning, ensemble-learning, bagging, bias-variance-tradeoff

In machine learning, why does bagging increase bias? I've read that using less data would lead to a worse estimate of the parameters, but isn't the expected value of the parameter constant regardless of sample size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle bagging is performed to reduce variance of fitted values as it increases the stability of the fitted values. In addition, as a rule of thumb I would say that: "*the  magnitudes of  the  bias are roughly the same for the bagged and the original procedure*" ([Bühlmann & Yu, 2002](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1031689014)). That is because bagging allows us to approximate relative complex response surfaces by practically smoothing over the learners' decision boundaries.

That said, you raise a good point about bagging "*using less data*"; my understanding is that this is a problem when the learners are potentially weak. Having less data makes the learning task more difficult. An obvious example would be an imbalanced dataset where a positive example is rather rare; in that case a simple majority rule for the bagging ensemble will probably be more harmful than helpful as indeed it will be more likely to misclassify the rare class - Berk's "*[Statistical Learning from a Regression Perspective](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Statistical-Learning-Regression-Perspective-Statistics/dp/3319440470)*", Sect. 4.4. on "*Some Limitations of Bagging*" touches upon this too. Let me note that this deteriorated performance is not totally surprising; bagging or any other procedure is not a silver bullet so it is expected that there will be cases that an otherwise helpful procedure (here bagging) makes things worse.

I think that the [Bühlmann & Yu, 2002](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1031689014) paper: "*Analyzing bagging*" is a canonical reference on the matter if you want to explore further. I also liked the [Strobl et al., 2007](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-8-25) paper: "*Bias in random forest variable importance measures: Illustrations, sources and a solution*", it focuses mostly on variable selection but makes a good point about how bagging affects the bias in that task.

Comment: BTW, welcome to the CV community!